# How to update Django model max_length value in database after tables have already been migrated

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need more characters available for the title and subtitle fields of a blog I made.  I would like to increase the max_length from 100 to 150.   Here is the table:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=99)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    body = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

Through another Q&A I took the advice to change the max_length in the model (in my case from 100 to 150) and type this in the command prompt:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

I then committed the changes and it allowed me to type more characters in but when I submitted the post it came up with a database error saying the fields can only take 100 characters.

How can I get the database to recognize the change in max_characters?

Comment: can you post file auto create by command `makemigrations` with lengh 100 and lengh 150?

Answer (score 0):

You can change it and re run the migrations again or do `python manage.py migrate my_app 0008_previous_migration` you can then delete the newer migration file with the error in it and re run the commands. 
You can do `python manage.py showmigrations my_app`

Comment: Will deleting the migrations file and re-migrating the changes mess up the data in the database?